# Where can i find information about upcoming iPhone developer events?

Tags: iphone, events

I need a list, or sg. like it about upcoming iPhone developer events...can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Probably:
[www.apple.com/developer/iphone](http://www.apple.com/developer/iphone)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post with a summary of iPhone & Mac conferences I found around the world... by no means authoritative nor complete I'm sure, but I hope it can be of help:

http://akosma.com/2009/10/01/iphone-and-mac-os-x-developer-conference-roundup/

Comment: By the way, two of those conferences are happening soon:

http://akosma.com/2009/12/11/upcoming-conferences-sdc-in-goteborg-and-iphone-dev-days-in-london/

:) (shameless self-promotion, I know)